# Finding the unit gradient vectors of an image

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing, gradient

I am trying to find the unit gradient vectors of an image but am not sure how to begin with this. Are there any specific OpenCV or other Python package commands that can be used to achieve this? The formula that I have to implement is the following:
[This will calculate the unit gradient vectors of the image in both the x and y directions.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QV0VJ.png)

Thank you in advance for any help or advice!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can with [opencv-python Sobel/Scharr](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d5/d0f/tutorial_py_gradients.html)

Unfortunately I won't have time to provide a detailed answer, however I can share a few commented snippets that will be great starting points:

computing:

- take an odd neighbourhood (e.g. 3x3)
- calculate horizontal change (`Gx = I(x+1,y) - I(x-1,y)`) and vertical change (`Gy = I(x,y+1) - I(x,y-1)`)
- calculate gradient magnitude (`mag = sqrt(Gx*Gx + Gy*Gy)`) and orientation (`o = math.degrees(atan2(Gy,Gx))`)

Sobel examples:

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2
# gradient kernels (3x3)

Gx = [ -1, 0, +1,
       -2, 0, +2,
       -1, 0, +1]

Gy = [ -1,-2, -1,
        0, 0,  0,
       +1,+2, +1]

# image
image = cv2.imread("yourImageHere.png")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.imshow("Original", image)

# compute gradients along the X and Y axis, respectively
gX = cv2.Sobel(gray, ddepth=cv2.CV_64F, dx=1, dy=0)
gY = cv2.Sobel(gray, ddepth=cv2.CV_64F, dx=0, dy=1)

# the `gX` and `gY` images are now of the floating point data type,
# so we need to take care to convert them back to an unsigned 8-bit
# integer representation so other OpenCV functions can utilize them
gX = cv2.convertScaleAbs(gX)
gY = cv2.convertScaleAbs(gY)

# combine the sobel X and Y representations into a single image
sobelCombined = cv2.addWeighted(gX, 0.5, gY, 0.5, 0)
```

manually computing magnitude and orientation

```py
# compute gradients along the X and Y axis, respectively
gX = cv2.Sobel(gray, cv2.CV_64F, 1, 0)
gY = cv2.Sobel(gray, cv2.CV_64F, 0, 1)

# compute the gradient magnitude and orientation respectively
mag = np.sqrt((gX ** 2) + (gY ** 2))
orientation = np.arctan2(gY, gX) * (180 / np.pi) % 180

# find all pixels that are within the upper and low angle boundaries
idxs = np.where(orientation >= args["lower_angle"], orientation, -1)
idxs = np.where(orientation <= args["upper_angle"], idxs, -1)
mask = np.zeros(gray.shape, dtype="uint8")
mask[idxs > -1] = 255

# show the images
cv2.imshow("Mask", mask)
```